# Python script orchestrator and simultaneous script execution

Tags: python, automation, plotly-dash, simultaneous

**Context**
I'm working on a Data Science Project in which I'm running a data analysis task on a dataset (let's call it *original* dataset) and creating a processed dataset (let's call this one *result*). The last one can be queried by a user by creating different plots through use of a Dash application. The system also makes some predictions on an attribute of this dataset thanks to ML models. Everything will work on an external VM of my company.

**What is my current "code"**
Currently I have these python scripts that create the *result* dataset (except the Dashboard one):

- `concat.py` (simply concatenates some files)
- `merger.py` (merges different files in the project directory)
- `processer1.py` (processes the first file needed for the analysis)
- `processer2.py` (processes a second file needed for the analysis)
- `Dashboard.py` (the Dash application)
- `ML.py` (runs a classic ML task, creates a report and an updated *result* dataset with some predictions)

**What I should obtain**
I'm interested in creating this kind of solution that will run the VM:

1. `Dashboard.py` runs 24/7 based on the existence of the "result" dataset, without it it's useless.
2. Every time there's a change in the project directory (new files every month are added), the system triggers the execution of `concat.py`, `merger.py`, `processer1.py` and `processer2.py`. Maybe a python script and the `watchdog` package can help to create this trigger mechanism? I'm not sure.
3. Once the execution above is done, the `ML.py` file is executed based on the "result" dataset and it's uploaded to the dashboard.
4. The `Dashboard.py` it's restarted with new csv file.

I would like to receive some help to understand what are the technologies necessary to get what I would like. Something like an example or maybe a source, so I can fully understand and apply what is right. I know that maybe I have to use a python script to orchestrate the whole system, maybe the same script that observes the directory or maybe not.

The most important thing is that the dashboard operates always. This is what creates the *need of running things simultaneously*. Just when the "result" csv dataset is completed and uploaded it is necessary to restart it, I think that for the users is best to keep the service continuity.
The users will feed the dashboard with new files in the observed directory. It's *necessary to create automation* by using "triggers" to execute the code, since they are not skilled users and they will not be allowed to use the VM bash (I suppose). Maybe I could think about creating a repetitive execution instead, like every month.

Company won't let me grant another VM or similar if it's needed, so I should do it just with a single VM.

**Premise**
This is the first time that I have to get "in production" something, and I have no experience at all. Could anyone help me to get the best approach? Thanks in advance.